# Difference between % and g command

Tags: vimrc

What is the difference between doing `:% [...]` and `:g [...]`. Does g require a regex to filter out what lines to apply to, or does it apply to all lines if no regex is given? For example:

To insert a `"` at the beginning of every line:

```
:% normal!I"
```

I'm guessing the equivalent `g` command would be:

```
:g/./ normal!I"
```

So, does `%` essentially translate to:

`/./` in a command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two are not really the same. In your example, `:g/./ normal!I"` will only prepend *non-empty* lines with a `"`, but it will not prepend the `"` to empty lines, which the `:%normal!I"` will do.

Yes, `:g` always needs a pattern and only acts on the lines that match that pattern. If you use an empty pattern (`//`), Vim will reuse the last pattern you used in a previous search, `:s` or `:g` command.

A closer similar to the `%` range would be using `:g/^/`, which is a pattern that will match *all* lines, including empty ones.

Using `:g` will have other side effects not in `%`, since when you use a pattern it is then saved as the last used pattern, which also presents itself visually if you have `'hlsearch'` enabled.

Also note that `:g` itself takes a range! You can use `:10,20g/pattern/command` to execute the command only on lines between 10 and 20 which *also* match the passed pattern. In fact, `:g/^/ normal!I"` is equivalent to `:%g/^/ normal!I"`. In other words, `:g` defaults to the `%` range when one is not passed explicitly.

The `%` range is exactly equivalent to `:1,$`, the range of lines between the first and the last one in the buffer.

Comment: great answer, thank you very much for the clarification on the above.

Comment: @David542 I tried to cover all angles 

Answer (score 2):

One other subtlety [not noted by filbranden](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/26122/343), is that the manner in which the two commands process the set of lines is a little different. The simplest example of the difference is probably to compare these two commands:

```
:%join
:g/^/join
```

The first will concatenate *every* line in your buffer into a single line. The second will concatenate every other line to its adjacent line (so you end up with half as many lines as before).

[`:help :global`](https://vimhelp.org/repeat.txt.html#%3Aglobal) explains why `:g` works in this way:

> The global commands work by first scanning through the [range] lines and
> marking each line where a match occurs (for a multi-line pattern, only the
> start of the match matters).
>
> In a second scan the [cmd] is executed for each marked line, as if the cursor
> was in that line.  For ":v" and ":g!" the command is executed for each not
> marked line.  ***If a line is deleted its mark disappears.***

(emphasis mine)

Comment: oh very interesting and good to know, thanks for the thorough explanation!